# Remove HTML code block from response using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, xml-parsing

I want to remove HTML code Block and CSS block from below code and get only XML code from above HTML code block. I want remove this HTML code block and want simple XML format code.

```
<FUSION-REPORT-FILE>
    <REPORT-FILE>
        <HEADER>
            <DATE-OF-REQUEST>22-02-2021</DATE-OF-REQUEST>
            <PREPARED-FOR>INS0000001</PREPARED-FOR>
            <PREPARED-FOR-ID>ABCD</PREPARED-FOR-ID>
            <DATE-OF-ISSUE>22-02-2021</DATE-OF-ISSUE>
            <REPORT-ID>xxyzD8989</REPORT-ID>
        </HEADER>
        <REQUEST>
            <NAME>ABX. XYZ</NAME>
            <DOB-DATE>1991-01-01</DOB-DATE>
            <PAN>PQR789895</PAN>
            <PHONE>9819941920</PHONE>
            <BRANCH-ID>59</BRANCH-ID>
        </REQUEST>
</FUSION-REPORT-FILE>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Fusion Report</title>
     <table>
   <td width="150"></td>

        <td align="left" width="300" valign="top">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" class="reportHead">FUSION REPORT
                            <br>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>                                  
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</html>
```

I want a response as like below without HTML Code block; want remove this HTML code block and want simple XML format code  as like below.

```
<FUSION-REPORT-FILE>
    <REPORT-FILE>
        <HEADER>
            <DATE-OF-REQUEST>22-02-2021</DATE-OF-REQUEST>
            <PREPARED-FOR>INS0000001</PREPARED-FOR>
            <PREPARED-FOR-ID>ABCD</PREPARED-FOR-ID>
            <DATE-OF-ISSUE>22-02-2021</DATE-OF-ISSUE>
            <REPORT-ID>xxyzD8989</REPORT-ID>
        </HEADER>
        <REQUEST>
            <NAME>ABX XYZ</NAME>
            <DOB-DATE>1991-01-01</DOB-DATE>
            <PAN>PQR789895</PAN>
            <PHONE>9819941920</PHONE>
            <BRANCH-ID>59</BRANCH-ID>
        </REQUEST>
</FUSION-REPORT-FILE>
```

Comment: In my opinion this you should be handled at backend itself.

Comment: actually I am using external api and this is response from this api but I want only this xml code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you konw the root tag of xml, you can use slice function in javascript to get part of the string.

```js
var str = `<FUSION-REPORT-FILE>
    <REPORT-FILE>
        <HEADER>
            <DATE-OF-REQUEST>22-02-2021</DATE-OF-REQUEST>
            <PREPARED-FOR>INS0000001</PREPARED-FOR>
            <PREPARED-FOR-ID>ABCD</PREPARED-FOR-ID>
            <DATE-OF-ISSUE>22-02-2021</DATE-OF-ISSUE>
            <REPORT-ID>xxyzD8989</REPORT-ID>
        </HEADER>
        <REQUEST>
            <NAME>ABX. XYZ</NAME>
            <DOB-DATE>1991-01-01</DOB-DATE>
            <PAN>PQR789895</PAN>
            <PHONE>9819941920</PHONE>
            <BRANCH-ID>59</BRANCH-ID>
        </REQUEST>
</FUSION-REPORT-FILE>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Fusion Report</title>
     <table>
   <td width="150"></td>
                                                                        <td align="left" width="300" valign="top">
                                                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                                                <tbody>
                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                        <td align="left" class="reportHead">FUSION REPORT
                                                                                            <br>
                                                                                            </td>
                                                                                        </tr>
                                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                                </table>
                                                                            </td>                                  
                                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                                </table>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                </table>
</html>`

var resultXml = str.slice(str.indexOf("<FUSION-REPORT-FILE>"),(str.indexOf("</FUSION-REPORT-FILE>")+21));

console.log(resultXml);
```